# Parameter values for parameter (n_neighbors) need to be a sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use the Skleanr module. However, my code is below

```
n_range = {'n_neighbors': range(1,100)}
knn_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = KNeighborsClassifier(), param_grid=n_range, scoring='f1_micro')
knn_search.fit(features_vector, train_labels)
```

results the error:

> Parameter values for parameter (n_neighbors) need to be a sequence.

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.x, function `range` returns a `range` object (which is not a sequence), not a list. You must convert it to a list yourself:

```
n_range = {'n_neighbors': list(range(1,100))}
```